# Format computer and install Ubuntu 17.04 server

Tags: server

I want to convert my installation from Ubuntu 17.04 Desktop to Ubuntu 17.04 Server. I want to format my computer and then install Ubuntu Server. How would I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should be able to just install Ubuntu Server. When it asks what you want to do with partitioning, there should be an option to use the entire disk -- choose that one and it will take care of the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and start in text only:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
systemctl disable  display-manager.service
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
reboot
```

Should start in terminal without graphical environment.

How would You revert it back to normal though if You want to go back?

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
systemctl enable display-manager.service
systemctl set-default graphical.target
reboot
```

Comparison of SysV Runlevels with systemd Targets

```
Runlevel ----- Target Units -------- Description
0 runlevel0 -- poweroff.target ----- Shut down and power off the system.
1 runlevel1 -- rescue.target ------- Set up a rescue shell.
2 runlevel2 -- multi-user.target --- Set up a non-graphical multi-user system.
3 runlevel3 -- multi-user.target --- Set up a non-graphical multi-user system.
4 runlevel4 -- multi-user.target --- Set up a non-graphical multi-user system.
5 runlevel5 -- graphical.target ---- Set up a graphical multi-user system.
6 runlevel6 -- reboot.target ------- Shut down and reboot the system.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How would I revert it back to normal though if I want to go back?

Comment: It deleted the display manager service. How do i bring it back?

Comment: @houseofkraft: I already edit the post to reply.